# string to hex for init_ntoa in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string

```
'0a0a0a02'
```

I would like to convert this to an IP Address format (`10.10.10.2`).

I am using the function - `socket.inet_ntoa()` in python.
The problem is the input to inet_ntoa() has to be of the form - '`\x0a\x0a\x0a\x02`'.
I tried appending '`\x`' to the original string using string concatenation, but it did not work.

```
>>> a = '0a'
>>> b = '\x'+a
ValueError: invalid \x escape
>>> b = '\\x' + a
>>> b
'\\x0a'
>>> b[1:]
'x0a'
>>> b[0:]
'\\x0a'
>>> print(b)
\x0a
>>> b=b+b+b+b
>>> print(b)
\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a
>>> socket.inet_ntoa(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.error: packed IP wrong length for inet_ntoa
>>>
```

How can I convert the string `0a0a0a02` to `\x0a\x0a\x0a\x02` in python?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`binascii.unhexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify).

```
>>> a='0a0a0a02'
>>> b=binascii.unhexlify(a) #Do take care of the imports
>>> inet_ntoa(b)
'10.10.10.2'
```